# Redirecting to app store using window.location

Tags: javascript, redirect, window

I have a script that checks to make sure that I am on a mobile device, grabs a feed with a list of apps and their app store addresses, and then calls on a function that, depending on what type of device it is, redirects the user to the correct app page.

```
var redirecToAppPage = function(device, types) {
    var url;
    if (device === 'android') {
        url = types.android;
    } else if (device === 'iphone' || device === 'ipod') {
        url = types.apple;
    } else if (device === 'ipad') {
        url = types.apple;
    } else if (device === 'blackberry') {
        url = types.phone;
    }
    if (url) {
        window.location = url;
        return false;
    }
    return url;
};
```

This is not working. The redirect never happens, and instead it executes the rest of the code on the page.

I have tried `window.location`, `window.location.href`, `window.location.assign(url)`, and `window.location.replace(url)`, none of them working. Any ideas why this wouldn't work?

Comment: Have you take a look about url value? console.log(url).

Comment: Yes, the URL value is an appropriate https://itunes.apple.com... link. When I go to the link directly, the link does pop up.

Answer (score 0):

I remake you function and worked well for me with this example:

```
function redirectToAppPage(device, types) {

    var url;
    if (device === 'android') {
        url = types.android;
    } else if (device === 'iphone' || device === 'ipod') {
        url = types.apple;
    } else if (device === 'ipad') {
        url = types.apple;
    } else if (device === 'blackberry') {
        url = types.phone;
    }

    if (url) {
        window.location.replace(url);
    }
}

// Example
var device = 'android';
var types = {
    android : "https://www.apple.com/itunes/"
}

redirectToAppPage(device, types);
```

Tried it with jsfiddle.

Comment: The links (see question comments above) are absolute URLs with proper protocols.